# hide <img> field if no data in database

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, css

So I'm pulling data from my database that users enter in. I want to avoid a blank img box if they have not submitted an image.

For example, if the user doesn't have an $image2 in his/her database, avoid displaying the class for that specific image. Is this even possible?

any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
<a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo 'pictures'.'/'.$userRow['image2'];?>" data-lightbox="example-set" >
<?php echo "<img class='example-image' src='pictures/".$userRow['image2']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";?>
</a>

<a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo 'pictures'.'/'.$userRow['image3'];?>" data-lightbox="example-set" >
<?php echo "<img class='example-image' src='pictures/".$userRow['image3']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use simple if{} condition like below:

```
<?php if(!empty($userRow['image2'])) { ?>
<a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo 'pictures'.'/'.$userRow['image2'];?>" data-lightbox="example-set" ><?php echo "<img class='example-image' src='pictures/".$userRow['image2']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";?></a>   
<?php } ?>

<?php if(!empty($userRow['image3'])) { ?>
<a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo 'pictures'.'/'.$userRow['image3'];?>" data-lightbox="example-set" ><?php echo "<img class='example-image' src='pictures/".$userRow['image3']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. I'll accept this answer in a couple minutes when it allows me!

Comment: @kenny glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Test your var before print it like for instead :

```
if(isset($userRow['image2']) && !empty($userRow['image2'])){
 // your code
}
```

**Source :**

`isset()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

`empty()` : http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php

Answer (score 0):

Add if condition before displaying img tag to check if  isset() image - means if image2 is set or not and image2 is not empty:

```
<a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo 'pictures'.'/'.$userRow['image2'];?>" data-lightbox="example-set" >
    <?php if(isset($userRow['image2']) && $userRow['image2'] != "")  { echo "<img class='example-image' src='pictures/".$userRow['image2']."' alt='Profile Pic'>"; } ?>
</a>

<a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo 'pictures'.'/'.$userRow['image3'];?>" data-lightbox="example-set" >
    <?php if(isset($userRow['image3']) && $userRow['image3'] != "") { echo "<img class='example-image' src='pictures/".$userRow['image3']."' alt='Profile Pic'>"; } ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and the [`empty()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function to check if the variable is set and not empty:

`isset()`

> Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

`empty()`

> Determine whether a variable

```
<?php if(isset($userRow['image2']) && !empty($userRow['image2'])){ { ?>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo 'pictures'.'/'.$userRow['image2'];?>" data-lightbox="example-set" >

<?php echo "<img class='example-image' src='pictures/".$userRow['image2']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";?></a>
<?php } ?>

<?php if(isset($userRow['image3']) && !empty($userRow['image3'])){ { ?>
    <a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo 'pictures'.'/'.$userRow['image3'];?>" data-lightbox="example-set" >

<?php echo "<img class='example-image' src='pictures/".$userRow['image3']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if(isset($userRow['image2']) && !empty($userRow['image2'])){ ?>
<a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo 'pictures'.'/'.$userRow['image2'];?>" data-lightbox="example-set" ><?php echo "<img class='example-image' src='pictures/".$userRow['image2']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";?></a> <?php } if(isset($userRow['image3']) && !empty($userRow['image3'])) { ?>
<a class="example-image-link" href="<?php echo 'pictures'.'/'.$userRow['image3'];?>" data-lightbox="example-set" ><?php echo "<img class='example-image' src='pictures/".$userRow['image3']."' alt='Profile Pic'>";?></a><?php } ?>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

If You are putting image source code then it will reflect on page if there is image or not in database...